# Asymptotic growth of group extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Is there some bound on the growth of finitely generated group extensions?
For instance Heisenberg integer group has polynomial growth of degree 4 and fits into the exact sequence $Z \rightarrow H \rightarrow Z \times Z $. Can we say that each extension $ Z \rightarrow Q \rightarrow Z^{n} $ has polynomial growth of degree at most $n+1$ or anything in this spirit concerning group extensions?

Comment: Hint: First work out the case when $Z$ is contained in the center of $Q$.

Comment: For the general question in the first sentence, the answer is an emphatic "no", as can be seen by a tiny little switch in the examples you ask about: the extension group $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to G \to \mathbb{Z}$ defined by the matrix $\pmatrix{2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1} \in \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})=\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}^2)$ has exponential growth.